# Open and close an electrical circuit

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have an application that one of it's features needs to control an electrical circuit of some device (open and close a circuit). Since i have no background in electronics i really don't know where to start.
I looked at some articles and found that i might need some kind of an RS232 relay device but i really don't have a clue if this is the right approach.
any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of circuit?  Low voltage(5-24V), high voltage(110-220V), something else?  What is your budget?  Is this a commercial/industrial application or a bench project?  What are your reliability requirements?  Speed?  Electrical noise environment?

Comment: @J This is a low budget private project, the voltage is 5V, as for the other questions you asked i really don't know about noise or speed.

Comment: You'll need to post to electronics.stackexchange.com, component selection is critical to make this work since a serial port cannot supply a lot of current and at least a diode is required.  They will expect you to document the make and model of the serial port hardware.

Comment: @Yoav if you are only turn 5V logic on and off you don't need a relay board, but a simple TTL IO module. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=usb%20io%20module&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=f55a776bf827b23e&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1143&bih=623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that this is a low-budget project - something like this would work :

http://www.easydaq.biz/PagesUSB/USBRelayCardProductsFRAME2.htm

Relay cards are available in USB, PCI, etc.  Google will help you find something in your price range, deliverable in your region, and with a suitable number of outputs.

There are DIY ultra-cheap options, however.  This would generally involve using the LPT printer port as a DIO port.  The 5V lines can be used to activate power transistors that drive coils in similar relays.  Have to solder your own for this kind of project.  LPT bits can be set with very simple low-level memory writes.

For commercial or industrial application the prices go up (as does reliability) and the correct unit would depend heavily on the specific application and environment.

Comment: another I was looking at http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/acatalog/Relay_Modules.html